# Implementing Windows Service app in Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, windows-services

I'm a very beginner in Windows Apps. I created a Windows Service app to send mail automatically at a specific time daily. Its taking some configuration values from app.config file. Also there is a web reference too in the service application. Then I installed the app using
InstallUtil /i %myapppath%\windowsservicevb.exe

It worked fine. But with less knowledge in this Windows service application I've no idea how to install that in Azure. Do I just need the exe file or I need to copy the app.config file also into the same directory in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You need to migrate your windows service on to a worker role in azure if you are going for azure PaaS.  example here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwasham/archive/2011/03/30/migrating-a-windows-service-to-windows-azure.aspx

Although if you are on an azure - IaaS VM then it is going to be the same as in the case of a windows machine locally.

Comment: Actually my main question is which are the files required to copy into my Azure VM to make the application work when there is a web reference and app.config file.

Comment: In azure VM it is the same as how you'll install in your local machine.installutil in the directory of your compiled service.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.. Actually do I need to copy all files inside the Debug directory of my project to the remote machine for the application to work (Including the web reference)

Comment: Generally for deployment you would compile it in release mode . Try copying all files .But is the web reference service available on the internet? Since it needs to be accessed from azure.

Comment: Yes...  thats from internet. OK I changed to release mode and compiled the application which generates a release folder and I will copy all the files inside it into Remote Azure VM

Comment: As a note, I agree with Aravind's implication that your solution would be simpler to manage as a PaaS solution. IaaS might be easier right now because it's a known quantity (from dev't and testing on your local box), but PaaS solutions provide a solid abstraction for actually creating web services.